# Only One fragment is displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a **spinner** item.When I click on position 2. I want the following code to execute.

```
if (pos == 2) {
    Log.e("TEST", "YOU CLICKED" + pos);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Log.e("TEST INSIDE FOR", "YOU CLICKED" + pos);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            // showFragOne();
            showFragOne();
            Log.e("TEST INSIDE FOR " + i, "YOU CLICKED" + pos);

            try {

                Thread.sleep(20000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (i %2 == 1) {
            // showFragTwo();
            showFragTwo();
            Log.e("TEST INSIDE FOR " + i, "YOU CLICKED" + pos);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(mCoreContext,"One Fragment added from feature app",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

What i want this code to do is change the Frame layout in 20s. But only the second fragment I am getting at last. Here **showFragTwo()** function:-

```
private void showFragTwo() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragmentTransaction ft = 
                        .getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (fragtwo.isAdded()) {
                    if (fragtwo.isHidden())
                        ft.show(fragtwo);
                    else
                        ft.hide(fragtwo);

                    ft.commit();
                } else {
                    ft.replace(com.example.coreapp.R.id.container, fragtwo,
                            "ADDFRAGTWO").commit();
                    ft.show(fragtwo);
                }
            }
```

Here **showFragOne()** function:-

```
private void showFragOne() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentTransaction ft =
                .getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (frag.isAdded()) {
            if (frag.isHidden())
                ft.show(frag);
            else
                ft.hide(frag);

            ft.commit();
        } else {

            ft.replace(com.example.coreapp.R.id.container, frag, "ADDFRAG")
                    .commit();
            ft.show(frag);
        }
    }
```

where i initialize frag and fragtwo at top to following to fragment class :-

```
frag = new AddFragmentOne();
fragtwo = new AddFragmentTwo();
```

I get the following as logcat o/p.

```
**02-28 04:56:34.250: E/TEST INSIDE FOR: YOU CLICKED2

02-28 04:56:34.290: E/TEST INSIDE FOR 0: YOU CLICKED2

02-28 04:56:54.350: E/TEST INSIDE FOR: YOU CLICKED2

02-28 04:56:54.350: E/TEST INSIDE FOR 1: YOU CLICKED2**
```

I am getting the logs message in o/p **BUT WHY THE FRAGMENT IS NOT GETTING DISPLAYED?**

**ONLY THE SECOND FRAGMENT I AM GETTING**

**If i comment second if statemnt I AM GETTING FIRST FRAGMENT**

Can anybody tell me where i am getting wrong?

Comment: I don't see commit() in  showFragOne() and showFragTwo() else

Comment: hey commit is there in both the function in the if statement.

Comment: Is this running on the UI thread?

Comment: what do you mean by UI thread? All the above work i am doing in One class only but not in the Oncreate method.

Comment: Ok so that's fine. Is `fragtwo.isAdded()` true in `showFragTwo()`?

Comment: here I am able to get the fragment individually but when i use if else to change the fragment in some time interval i am getting the second fragment only not first.

Comment: You mean, only the second fragment is showed after 20 seconds ?

Comment: yes, if i use above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you make the Thread sleep 20 seconds and its likely the Ui Thread.
You should replace this `Thread.sleep()` statement by a `Timer` that shows the appropriate fragment :

```
if(pos == 2) {
    showFragOne();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            showFragTwo();
        }
    }, 20000);
}
```

---

To complete the answer based on commentaries : I suggest you make one method

```
/** This method shows the fragment whose 'number' is {@code fragmentNumber}. */
public void showFrag(int fragmentNumber) {
    Fragment f = fragments.get(fragmentNumber); // fragments can be a List for example
    // Then use the code you already have to show fragment 'f'
}
```

Then, you can modify the preceding code like this :

```
if(pos == 2) {
    final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0); // Because use inside TimerTask requires a final variable
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count.get() < MAX_FRAG_INDEX)
                showFrag(count.getAndIncrement);
            else
                cancel();
        }
    }, 0, 2000);
}
```

Comment: But, What i want is I want to toggle the Fragment every 2 sec (any small time interval) for around some 50 times by using for loop. something like for(i=0;i<50;i++) for 2 or more fragment.

Comment: Here i am using Two fragment only but i want to use some more fragmnet to toggle that fragment view based on i value using if else. i tried your answer with that it didnt worked for me.